# is there a way to make changes to a Revit model from VR in real time?

Tags: virtual-reality, revit-api

There are various methods to  interact with Revit models in VR, enabling a real-time update of the VR environment, when changes in the Revit model are done. I am wondering if there is a way for the reverse interaction, means, making changes on the Revit model when changes in the Virtual reality environment are done?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a number of samples connecting desktop and cloud years ago, cf. the [FireRatingCloud sample](https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud). The Revit API requires a Revit executable running on a Windows desktop machine. You can hook that up to a web service, if you like, and interact in (more or less) real time. Another option is to use the [Autodesk Forge Platform](https://forge.autodesk.com). Forge [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page) enables interaction with and modification of a Revit model in the cloud, with no Revit installation running locally.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for the quick reply and the suggestions! To be honest, I haven't worked with Forge so far. Are there any limitation of the scope which is modifiable trough Forge? Can I access and modify materials and material properties from the "outside" too?